# iOS - Animating UIButton ImageView Images causes button to be 'selected' after

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, animation

I am trying to animate the images of a `UIButton`. The animation runs fine, but afterwards it always puts a gray tint on the button (*as if it was being **highlighted/selected***).

Code:

```
NSArray *images = [[NSArray alloc] init];
images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
          [UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE1],
          [UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE2],
          [UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE3],
          [UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE4],
          nil];
iconBobble.imageView.animationImages = images;
iconBobble.imageView.animationDuration = 1.5;
iconBobble.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[iconBobble.imageView startAnimating];
```

Comment: may be you have image in gray, which stays in the end of the animation..?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`adjustsImageWhenHighlighted` property will solve your problem.

This code will solve your problem....

```
-(IBAction)animateButton:(id)sender
{
    [iconBobble setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:NO];

    NSArray *images = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
              [UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE1],
              [UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE2],
              [UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE3],
              [UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE4],
              nil];

    float animationDuration = 1.5;
    iconBobble.imageView.animationImages = images;
    iconBobble.imageView.animationDuration = animationDuration;
    iconBobble.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    [iconBobble.imageView startAnimating];
    [self performSelector:@selector(stopButtonAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:animationDuration];
}
-(void)stopButtonAnimation
{
    [iconBobble.imageView stopAnimating];
}
```

This is working fine for me :-)

Comment: Awesome! That did the trick. One side note, I didn't need to include the 'stopButtonAnimation' method or call. Animation stops on its own. Maybe you have other code executing as a callback in yours, but the animation will stop on it's own after the designated time. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Set `yourButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`